# How to enable SSL on Tomcat

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I have a license server that is running Tomcat. I have been asked to enable SSL and I am clueless as where to start. I have the following files:

```
FQDM.csr
FQDM.key
FQDM.crt
FQDM.pkcs7
```

Outside of the `.crt` file, which I understand it to be certificate filename, and the `.csr`, which I understand is the Certificate Signing Request, I don't know what the files mean or how they work together. I have directions, but don't know what the commands expect.

As as example:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -keysize 2048
```

That will generate a `keystore.jks`. There was already a .keystore, after the fresh install.

The next command asks me to:

```
keytool -import -alias root-keystore  keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file <filename_of_the_chain_certificate>
```

Which of the above listed files is the Chain Certificate?

Comment: This would belong on Server Fault in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you do not need to create a new keystore, but you rather want to import your certificate to the keystore. Since you does not seem to have the general picture of how this things work I would suggest reading about [SSL and Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#SSL_and_Tomcat), and it should explain how to import certificates and enable SSL.

Hope it help you in the right direction.